Multilayered Rows for SAS Proc Report
Is there a way to have a multilayered row setup in SAS?  I have too many columns in my .rtf output, and the overflow is placed in a separate table. This is the desired result:
<b>          ColumnA  ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD</b>
<b>          ColumnE  ColumnF ColumnG ColumnH</b>
<b>Person 1    A1        B1      C1      D1</b>
<b>            E1        F1      G1      H1</b>
<b>Person 2    A2        B2      C2      D2</b>
<b>            E2        F2      G2      H2</b>


I suspect you are trying to ask how to display 2 observations of data in 4 lines instead of 2.  It would be clearer if you included the source data for the listing you are displaying.

You may want to read [ask]

You can create customized output with DATA _null_ and ODSOUT component object.
Documentation and conference papers cover the topic in great detail.
Example:
data have;
input (ID A B C D E F G H) ($) ;
datalines ;
Caine A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1
Abel  A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2
;

ods listing close;
ods html file='report.html';

title 'Custom table from DATA _NULL_ and ODSOUT Component Object' ;
data _null_ ;
  set have end=end;
  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    declare odsout oo() ;
    oo.table_start() ;
    oo.row_start(type:'h');
      oo.cell_start(); oo.cell_end();
      oo.cell_start(data:'A') ; oo.cell_end();
      oo.cell_start(data:'B') ; oo.cell_end();
      oo.cell_start(data:'C') ; oo.cell_end();
      oo.cell_start(data:'D') ; oo.cell_end();
    oo.row_end();
    oo.row_start(type:'h');
      oo.cell_start(); oo.cell_end();
      oo.cell_start(data:'E') ; oo.cell_end();
      oo.cell_start(data:'F') ; oo.cell_end();
      oo.cell_start(data:'G') ; oo.cell_end();
      oo.cell_start(data:'H') ; oo.cell_end();
    oo.row_end();
  end ;

  oo.row_start(type:'d');
    oo.cell_start(data:ID); oo.cell_end();
    oo.cell_start(data:A) ; oo.cell_end();
    oo.cell_start(data:B) ; oo.cell_end();
    oo.cell_start(data:C) ; oo.cell_end();
    oo.cell_start(data:D) ; oo.cell_end();
  oo.row_end();
  oo.row_start(type:'d');
    oo.cell_start(); oo.cell_end();
    oo.cell_start(data:E) ; oo.cell_end();
    oo.cell_start(data:F) ; oo.cell_end();
    oo.cell_start(data:G) ; oo.cell_end();
    oo.cell_start(data:H) ; oo.cell_end();
  oo.row_end();
  if end then oo.table_end() ;
run ;

ods html close;


